# Getting CMake to understand absolute symbolic links when cross-compiling for Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

When cross compiling with CMake, I use a toolchain file which sets up the linker to look in a local copy of the root filesystem of the embedded (Linux) target.

Things come unstuck for a few fundamental libraries like `libm` or `librt` which are usually a symbolic link to an absolute location which cannot be resolved.

For example, on the target rootfs, librt is a symbolic link at `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so` which points to `/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.6`

I thought setting the option `CMAKE_SYSROOT` to the root of the root filesystem would be enough to let CMake and/or gcc work out the link, but this doesn't work.

For now I'm just manually adjusting the links to be relative and then everything links ok. I assume there must be something I'm missing about cross-compiling with CMake though?

What is the paradime for ensuring cross-compilation and linking against libraries in a root filesystem?

The root filesystem is generated with the `debootstrap` tool. The complications have arisen from requiring to build the project against both Wheezy and Jessie root filesystem targets.

Comment: This is a filesystem-level problem. Try this in your home directory: `echo 'a' > a && ln -s /a b && cat b` - now consider what you'd expect `cat`, and _every other program ever capable of calling `open()`_, to do in order to "understand" that and do what you'd like.

Comment: @Notlikethat why don't you do an answer with "do what you'd like."? You've explained the basics of symbolic linking and nothing to do with answering the question. The answer could easily be - "CMake and/or gcc cannot do any such translation and you have to modify the root file system to link against it.". I just want to know from others what the recommended way of cross-compiling and linking using a rootfs is with CMake and gcc. Thanks.

Comment: The time I ran up against this I just did exactly what you've already mentioned - manually rewrote links until it stopped failing (I did find some scary scripts to supposedly relativise all symlinks in an entire filesystem automatically, but no thanks). The point of my comment was just to defuse the apparent expectation in the first half of the question, which suggested some level of misunderstanding. There may well _be_ some neat filesystem-level solution (chroot magic?) but I don't know of one, hence I don't have an answer to add. I'm as keen to know as you are!

Comment: ...and the general point being that the question isn't tool-specific at all; rather, it boils down to "What is the most practical way to compile against a mounted foreign filesystem full of absolute symlinks?"

Comment: @Notlikethat Thanks for your comments, I was convinced that I'd missing something to make this easier!