# How to force gcc linker to respect --sysroot when dereferencing absolute symlinks during cross-compiling?

Tags: gcc, linker, cross-compiling, symlink

My target rootfs contains symlinks like this:

target_rootfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so -> /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0

Therefore, when I compile and link with --sysroot=target_rootfs it incorrectly jumps out of target rootfs and read files from the host /lib directory.

This question was already asked in:
[Getting CMake to understand absolute symbolic links when cross-compiling for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834580/getting-cmake-to-understand-absolute-symbolic-links-when-cross-compiling-for-lin)
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/108351/cross-compiling-and-sysroot
and they suggested rewriting the target rootfs by converting absolute symlinks to relative.
But what if target rootfs is read-only?
Is there a way to trick gcc to apply --sysroot when dereferencing symlinks?